# Ruby compare objects

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [=== vs. == in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422223/vs-in-ruby)

I was wondering what the difference is between the == and the === comparison in Ruby? What is the general definition of when to use which?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422223/vs-in-ruby | None they are not related. One is equality the other is subsumption.

Comment: @Philippe You are right that would have been my answer but I couldn't find it when I searched for it..

Comment: No worries, I found it by luck ... I was testing different ways to search for characters here.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [What does the “`===`” operator do in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4467538/#4467823) and [`===` vs. `==` in Ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3422223/#3422349).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never actually *call* `===` yourself. The *language* calls `===` behind the scenes when you're using `case` statements: http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/

If you want different behavior for a class in `case` statements than the standard `Object#===` provides, then you'll need to redefine it. But I've never really looked hard enough to find a reason to replace the standard definition. :)

Answer (score 1):

'===' is a broader (weaker) notion than the equality '=='. '===' becomes true not only under equality, but also under notions such as, matching a regular expression, being an instance of a class, etc. Despite what sarnold says, I actually do use '===' as a shorthand for 'kind_of?'. Where A is a class,

```
A === a
```

can be used as a shorthand of

```
a.kind_of?(A)
```

One thing to be careful is that, despite its appearance, it is not commutative. So,

```
a === A
```

will not work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

== is used for equality in conditional statements like if, unless, etc. === is used for determining equality in case statements.