# What's the difference between == and === when comparing 2 object

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [=== vs. == in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422223/vs-in-ruby)

```
Fixnum == 2.class 
#=> true

Fixnum === 2.class
#=> false
```

why `===` doesn't work? and how can I know the method .=== belong to(right now I guess it invoke the `Object#==`, or `Object#===`), but how can I make sure of that?

Comment: I would assume that `==` means they have the same value, whilst `===` means they are the same object?

Comment: As answered many times before on SO, `===` also take the type of the object into account.

Comment: @TyrantWave and @Ash -- `===` doesn't have specifics for type checking. When it's overridden in sub classes of `Object`. For example, `Range#===` does an `include?` on the object. It doesn't care about types in this situation

Comment: This is a duplicate of [What does the “`===`” operator do in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4467538/#4467823), [`===` vs. `==` in Ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3422223/#3422349) and [Ruby compare objects](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5230096/).

Comment: @TyrantWave: Then you would assume wrong.

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko: As answered many times before on SO, that's (Pardon my French) bullshit.

Comment: @Jorg: Apparently so. Well, at least I learned something as well =D

Comment: @yozloy Please search SO before asking questions. When you enter your question title you would have seen a ton of these questions already answered. You would have had your answer had you clicked one of them. Assuming my answer answers your question please mark it so. I'm going to add the links provided by @sawa and @Jörg W Mittag into my answer

Comment: @Jorg: Yet another FAQ that's a Frequently Wrongly Answered Question, just like getting instance methods, or what `||=` means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicates:

- [=== vs. == in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422223/vs-in-ruby)
- [What does the "===" operator do in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4467538/#4467823)
- [=== vs. == in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3422223/#3422349)
- [Ruby compare objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5230096/)

Case equality. See the documentation for [Object#===](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Object:%3D%3D%3D). This method is usually overridden in subclasses of `Object`. For example, [Module#===](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Module:%3D%3D%3D):

> Case Equality--Returns true if anObject is an instance of mod or one of mod’s descendants. Of limited use for modules, but can be used in case statements to classify objects by class.

```
>> Module.new === Module
=> false
>> Module === Module.new
=> true
```

[Regexp#===](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Regexp:%3D%3D%3D) is another one, in which case it's a synonym of `=~`:

```
a = "HELLO"
case a
when /^[a-z]*$/; print "Lower case\n"
when /^[A-Z]*$/; print "Upper case\n"
else;            print "Mixed case\n"
end
```

An example in IRB:

```
>> "a" === /a/
=> false
>> /a/ === "a"
=> true
```

Remember, the first one returns false because you're doing `===` on `String` which isn't the same thing. In the second example we're doing `===` on `Regexp`

And finally, [Range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html#M000699) is quite a good one it calls `include?` on the Range object and passes your value in:

```
>> (1..100) === 3
=> true
>> (1..100) === 300
=> false
```

For a list of these, check out [RubyDoc.info](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2) core documentation and search for `===` in the methods area in the left side frame

Answer (score 0):

The == usually only checkes the values of both arguments, when ==== checks the types, too.

Comment: `===` doesn't check types unless one of the sub-classes has overridden it to work this way