# Ruby string compare: == vs ===

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [=== vs. == in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422223/vs-in-ruby)

Can I assume they are the same?

```
if foo == "bar"
```

vs

```
if foo === "bar"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

<strike>They are not the same. The short answer is that `==` checks if the values are the same, but type-casts if necessary. `===` is only true if the values AND types are the same.</strike>

```
0 == "0" #=> true
0 === "0" #=> false
0 === 0 #=> true
```

There are (literally) millions of discussions about this on the internet, as this is not, by a long-shot, a Ruby-specific thing. Try a Google search if you'd like more information.

**Edit**

I made a mistake, this is incorrect.

Comment: -1, `0 == "0" # => false` in Ruby. You confuse `===` with exact equality operator in JavaScript and other languages. In Ruby this is different! See the link by Greg Hewgill, he posted it 1 hour before you answered.