# Assign an instance variable based on a linked table field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a system that checks whether the current user is authorized to edit a record. I think the way to do it is to assign and instance variable of @user to the linked ID of the displayed record and a private function that redirects unless `@user` = `current_user`, but when I do this, I get redirect behavior every time (even when a user owns the record).

Here is the controller setup

```
def edit 
    @deal = Deal.find(params[:id]) 
    @user = User.where(params[:id] === @deal.user_id)
    correct_user
  end
...
private

  def correct_user
    unless @user === current_user
      redirect_to root_path
      flash[:error] = 'You can only edit deals that you own'
    end
  end
```

The user and deal models are related through has many and owns

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :deals
...
class Deal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
```

And the schema for deals (user id is assigned at creation to `user_id`)

```
 create_table "deals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "headline"
    t.string   "matter"
    t.text     "summary"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_deals_on_user_id"
  end
```

The project is setup with Devise so those helpers are also available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `==` instead of `===` you just want to compare `@user` with `current_user`

```
@user == current_user
```

See the difference here [=== vs. == in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422223/vs-in-ruby)

Also You need to change

```
@user = User.where(params[:id] === @deal.user_id)
```

to

```
@user = @deal.user
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so where to start...

First of all, don't use `===` to compare records, use `==` instead.

Secondly:

```
def edit 
  @deal = Deal.find(params[:id]) 
  @user = User.find_by(params[:id]: @deal.user_id)
  correct_user
end
```

When trying to find user, you need to provide AR options as a hash, instead of boolean parameter. Either use `find` if you want to raise exception when record not found, or `find_by` to simply return nil.

And in `correct_user` again use `==` instead of `===`.

However this code still isn't very pretty and could use some refactoring ;)