# Using 'case' with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a case statement which looks at two conditions, like this:

```
roll1 = rand(1..6)
roll2 = rand(1..2)

result = case[roll1, roll2]
  when [1..3 && 1]
    "Low / Low"
  when [4..6 && 1]
    "High / Low"
  when [1..3 && 2]
    "Low / High"
  when [4..6 && 2]
    "JACKPOT!!"
end

puts result
```

I'd love to get this working. I'd prefer to understand why my example fails.

**Edited to add:**

Thanks for all the feedback! Inspired, I realized that combining the two case variables allows me to collapse them into a single value for a simple switch statement...

```
roll1 = rand(1..6)
roll2 = rand(1..2)

if roll2 == 1
  roll2 = 10
elsif roll2 == 2
  roll2 = 20
end

result = case(roll1 + roll2)
  when 11..13
    "Low / Low"
  when 14..16
    "High / Low"
  when 21..23
    "Low / High"
  when 24..26
    "JACKPOT!!"
end

puts result
```

While this solves my immediate problem, it doesn't advance my underlying knowledge -- it's a trifling insight compared to all the awesome feedback I've received. Sincere thanks!

Comment: As well as [`include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Range.html#method-i-include-3F) which has already been mentioned, [`cover?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) and [`between?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems with your code. First of all, this:

```
[1..3 && 1]
```

is an array with one element. Since `..` has lower precedence than `&&`, you're really writing `1..(3 && 1)` which is just a complicated way of saying `1..1`. That means that your `case` is really:

```
case[roll1, roll2]
  when [1..1]
    "Low / Low"
  when [4..1]
    "High / Low"
  when [1..2]
    "Low / High"
  when [4..2]
    "JACKPOT!!"
end
```

The second problem is that `Array` doesn't override the `===` operator that `case` uses so you'll be using `Object#===` which is just an alias for `Object#==`. This means that your `case` is equivalent to:

```
if([roll1, roll2] == [1..1])
  "Low / Low"
elsif([roll1, roll2] == [4..1])
  "High / Low"
elsif([roll1, roll2] == [1..2])
  "Low / High"
elsif([roll1, roll2] == [4..2])
  "JACKPOT!!"
end
```

`[roll1, roll2]` will never equal `[some_range]` because `Array#==` compares element by element and `roll1` will never `==` a range; furthermore, you're also comparing arrays with different sizes.

All that means that you have a complicated way of saying:

```
result = nil
```

I'd probably just use an `if` for this:

```
result = if (1..3).include?(roll1) && roll2 == 1
           'Low / Low'
         elsif (4..6).include?(roll1) && roll2 == 1
           'High / Low'
         ...
```

or you could use `===` explicitly:

```
result = if (1..3) === roll1 && roll2 == 1
           'Low / Low'
         elsif (4..6) === roll1 && roll2 == 1
           'High / Low'
         ...
```

but again, watch out for the low precedence of `..`.

Comment: Would it be a bad idea to monkey patch `===` to `Array` (so that elements are compared with `===`) and to then use `when [1..3, 2]`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I'd tend to say that monkey patching to change standard behavior is a bad idea, monkey patching to add methods tends to be less of a bad idea. Debugging a NoMethodError is usually easy, debugging an operator that isn't behaving normally is a little harder. I didn't mention that option because the OP is new at Ruby and monkey is dangerous.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm also new at Ruby, that's why I was wondering. I had already done it just to see whether I can, but I lack the judgement of whether it's good. And now I agree, changing existing behavior like this is probably bad.

Comment: Hmm... what do you think about adding that `===` in a *subclass* and then using `when Case[1..3, 1]`? Demo: https://ideone.com/Xq6qd7

Comment: @StefanPochmann Something like that is clever, reads well, is narrowly targeted, and doesn't have a lot of sharp edges so yeah, I'd support that sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks, turned it into an answer now. And thanks for your answer pretty much pointing out exactly what I had to do :-)

Comment: This is really helpful -- made clear I was using [] as *punctuation* rather than to deliberately create an array. Total rookie mistake.

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers explain in more detail, your `when [1..3 && 2]` doesn't work because that's actually `when [1..2]` and because arrays don't compare their elements with `===` (which `when` does and which the range would need to do).

Here's another way to make it work, by fixing exactly those two issues.

First, use `[1..3, 2]` instead of `[1..3 && 2]`, so the two conditions don't get combined but stay separated in the array. Then, to get `===` used, create a subclass of `Array` that compares elements with `===` instead of `==`. And use it in the `when` condition instead of a normal array. Full code:

```
roll1 = rand(1..6)
roll2 = rand(1..2)

class Case < Array
  def ===(other)
    zip(other).all? { |x, y| x === y }
  end
end

result = case[roll1, roll2]
  when Case[1..3, 1]
    "Low / Low"
  when Case[4..6, 1]
    "High / Low"
  when Case[1..3, 2]
    "Low / High"
  when Case[4..6, 2]
    "JACKPOT!!"
end

puts roll1, roll2, result
```

That [for example prints](https://ideone.com/Xq6qd7):

```
6
2
JACKPOT!!
```

I guess whether this is good / worth it for you depends on your actual use case. But I like it. And as a Ruby beginner myself, this little exercise helped me understand better how `when` and `===` work.

Also see the discussion under @muistooshort's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47539446/1672429) for some thoughts about this.

And this answer about what `===` does was also very illuminating:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3422349/1672429

Answer (score 2):

### Case Statements, Expressions, and Case Equality

The when-statement doesn't really work the way you seem to think, and neither does an array literal. In its basic form, `case` compares a top-level expression to the expressions in a when statement using the threequals operator (`===`).

In Ruby, almost everything is an expression. In your example, you're trying to match an array of values to an array that resolves to a single-element array. Consider:

```
[1..3 && 2]
#=> [1..2]

[1..3 && 2].count
#=> 1

[1..3 && 2].map &:class
#=> [Range]
```

Basically, your top-level array never matches any of the array expressions you're providing as conditions. What you want is probably something like this:

```
result = case
when (1..3).include?(roll1) && roll2.eql?(1)
  "Low / Low"
else
  raise "invalid comparison"
end
```

In this type of construction, you're not using a threequals expression with a top-level value to compare against. Instead, you're constructing a truthy or falsey Boolean from a pair of expressions. Flesh this out with additional when statements, and then debug your expressions if you're still getting invalid comparisons.

Comment: I really like the way you're evaluating the statements to determine what they *really* say -- truly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Except in the case of `“JACKPOT!!”` you have two separate problems, which are easier to deal with by treating them separately.

```
def result_of_rolls(roll1, roll2)
  if (4..6).cover?(roll1) && roll2 == 2
    "JACKPOT!!"
  else
    "%s / %s" % [(1..3).cover?(roll1) ? "Low" : "High",
                 roll2 == 1 ? "Low" : "High"]
  end
end

result_of_rolls(2,1) #=> "Low / Low"
result_of_rolls(4,1) #=> "High / Low"
result_of_rolls(3,2) #=> "Low / High"
result_of_rolls(5,2) #=> "JACKPOT!!"
```

If there were three or more rolls, rather than just two, it can be seen that this approach would be much more efficient than one that examined all the combinations of values of `roll1`, `roll2`, `roll3`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If your example is not just an artificial [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the general case but your actual problem, or if your actual problem is really similar, here are a few more ideas:

Treat as two independent problems, combine, handle the special case:

```
result = "#{roll1 < 4 ? 'Low' : 'High'} / #{roll2 < 2 ? 'Low' : 'High'}".
           sub('High / High', 'JACKPOT!!')
```

Same idea written differently:

```
result = [roll1 < 4, roll2 < 2].
           map { |low| low ? 'Low' : 'High' }.
           join(' / ').
           sub('High / High', 'JACKPOT!!')
```

Same again but a bit silly:

```
result = [roll1 < 4, roll2 < 2].
           join(' / ').
           gsub('true', 'Low').gsub('false', 'True').
           sub('High / High', 'JACKPOT!!')
```

Using booleans because they just need `==` comparison:

```
result = case [roll1 > 3, roll2 > 1]
         when [false, false]
           "Low / Low"
         when [true, false]
           "High / Low"
         when [false, true]
           "Low / High"
         when [true, true]
           "JACKPOT!!"
         end
```

(`case [(4..6) === roll1, roll2 == 2]` would work as well. And note I [indented differently](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#indent-conditional-assignment).)

Combine the rolls into a single number:

```
result = case roll1 * (-1)**roll2
         when -3..-1
           "Low / Low"
         when -6..-4
           "High / Low"
         when 1..3
           "Low / High"
         when 4..6
           "JACKPOT!!"
         end
```

Same idea written differently:

```
result = case roll2 * 10 + roll1
         when 11..13
           "Low / Low"
         when 14..16
           "High / Low"
         when 21..23
           "Low / High"
         when 24..26
           "JACKPOT!!"
         end
```

Same again, just different code style:

```
result = case roll1 * (-1)**roll2
         when -3..-1 then "Low / Low"
         when -6..-4 then "High / Low"
         when  1..3  then "Low / High"
         when  4..6  then "JACKPOT!!"
         end
```

Comment: Just for clarification - this was an artificial MCVE. Original problem was to offer results of a rand(1..100) number with a second dimension, a, b, or c. I didn't want to write 3 different case statements duplicating results. Then I figured out I could write a single case statement by converting the second dimension to an integer, combine with original random number, and use when 1..10 || 101..105 || 201..203 do x. Just for clarification.

Comment: @GeorgeTucker Ok, thanks. That's what I suspected and why I wrote my other answer first. Still sounds similar, though, so maybe some of these solutions could be adapted to it.