# Ruby. How is the case equality method implemented in the class Class?

Tags: ruby, class, case

Is there any special Reason why the `===` and the `==` methods are implemented differently in the class `Class`?

```
"".class == String
#=> true

"".class === String
#=> false
```

Comment: There's more fun: if you replace `String` with `""` in your example, you get opposite results :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can further simplify your question I think.
I believe you are asking is why

```
String == String # true
```

But

```
String === String # false
```

I think it's semi consistent by Ruby. the === equality asks if right side is a member of the left side.

So

```
Class === String
```

Is true since String is a member of Class. And indeed String is not a member of String.

What I do find weird though is that

```
5 === 5 # returns true
```

Imo it should return false to be consistent with String === String returning false, but for primitives Ruby has this quirk, probably so it works well with case statements.

Comment: Further read on === and case statements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3422349/1032663

Comment: It makes more sense when you think of it in terms of `case` statements: `when 1, 2, 3` matches the given values. `when 1..3, 5` matches everything within the range plus 5. `when ->(i) { i.odd? }` matches odd numbers. `when Integer` matches all integers. The "inconsistency" is actually pretty neat.

Comment: Also note that `===` behaves that way because of the different receivers. There's [`Module#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Module.html#3D-3D-3D-method), [`Range#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Range.html#3D-3D-3D-method), [`Proc#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Proc.html#3D-3D-3D-method) and more. Only the default [`Object#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Object.html#3D-3D-3D-method) is equivalent to `==`.

Answer (score 2):

The goal of `===` (called "case quality") is to be used within `case` statement. Creators decided that aliasing `===` with `is_a?` for `Module` instances works best with a common scenarios like:

```
def do_sth(object)
  case object
    when :nothing then ...
    when String then ...
    when Hash then ...
    else ...
end
```

`===` should (almost) never be explicitly used outside of the `case` statement.

Comment: _"aliasing `===` with `is_a?`"_ – it might be worth noting that this only holds true for modules. In particular, Ruby won't check for `object.is_a?(:nothing)`

Comment: @Stefan - Good catch, added.